# MYSQL Update Command via VBScript

Tags: mysql, vbscript

Having problems getting a csv imported into a MYSQL database to update existing data.  The importing new data works fine, just getting errors updating.

```
`CSVSerial = arrServiceList(0)
CSVAssetTag = arrServiceList(1)
CSVLocation = arrServiceList(2)
CSVRoom = arrServiceList(3)
CSVCheckedOutTo = arrServiceList(4)

commandText = "Update Inventory Set Room = CSVRoom, Location = CSVLocation, AssetTag = CSVAssetTag, CheckedOutTo = CSVCheckedOutTo where SerialNumber = CSVSerial"`
```

I've tried doing $CSVSerial, '$CSVSerial', 'CSVSerial', they don't seem to recognize any of them.  If I do a

```
Msgbox (CSVSerial & "," & CSVRoom & "," & CSVLocation & "," & CSVAssettag & "," & CSVCheckedOutTo)
```

all the data is correct there.  I'm sure it's something simple, just don't have alot of MySQL experience.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query just uses the literal strings `CSVRoom`, `CSVLocation`, etc. rather than their values. The `$CSVSerial` won't work in VB - that's a PHP thing (plus some other languages). In addition, if these are string values they need to be surrounded by single quotes. Try something like this instead:

```
commandText = "Update Inventory Set Room = '" & CSVRoom & "', " & _
    "Location = '" & CSVLocation & "', " & _
    "AssetTag = '" & CSVAssetTag & "', " & _
    "CheckedOutTo = '" & CSVCheckedOutTo & "' where SerialNumber = '" & CSVSerial & "'"
```

I've assumed all the columns are strings. If any are numbers you don't need the single quotes around them but then again they shouldn't hurt either.

---

**Addendum**: Followup question is how to update the columns only if they're *not* blank or null.

To test for blank or null, you can use a condition like this:

```
Room IS NULL OR Room = ''
```

... or like this:

```
COALESCE(Room, '') = ''
```

The second one is shorter so I'll go with that because the command lines are getting pretty long. The basic MySQL command goes like this:

```
UPDATE Inventory SET
  Room = CASE WHEN COALESCE(Room, '') = '' THEN Room ELSE 'new value' END,
  ...
```

So if Room is `''` or `NULL` it's set to its existing `''` or `NULL` value. If not, it's set to the new value.

Here's how it looks in VBScript. This is untested because I don't have VBScript available.

```
commandText = "UPDATE Inventory SET " & _
  "Room = CASE WHEN COALESCE(Room, '') = '' THEN Room ELSE '" & CSVRoom & "' END, " & _
  "Location = CASE WHEN COALESCE(Location, '') = '' THEN Location ELSE '" & CSVLocation & "' END, " & _
  "AssetTag = CASE WHEN COALESCE(AssetTag, '') = '' THEN AssetTag ELSE '" & CSVAssetTag & "' END, " & _
  "CheckedOutTo = CASE WHEN COALESCE(CheckedOutTo, '') = '' THEN CheckedOutTo ELSE '" & CSVCheckedOutTo & "' END " & _
  "WHERE SerialNumber = '" & CSVSerial & "'"
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked perfect.  Is there a way inside of the commandtext to not update if the field is blank?

Comment: Do you mean for each column? For example, update `Room` unless it's  blank, update `Location` unless it's blank, and so forth? And by "blank" do you mean a zero-length column value, or do you mean `NULL`? Or either?

Comment: correct, if it's blank or null, I don't want to overwrite what's currently there.

Comment: Got it Phillip. I've updated my answer to show how to do this; the answer assumes that if the `Room` column is blank or null it won't be updated, but if it already has a value it will be updated. Hope I got that the right way around :) If not just let me know.